# sh script not working after pulling from git

Tags: git, shell

I have created couple of shell scripts which helps in performing the database deployment activities. Those .sh and .properties files works absolutely fine. However I have pushed those files to git repository and pulled the same files and trying to run but its throwing some unknown error.
The VM is running with Linux  RHEL 7.5 version.

Also FYI, the same .sh and .properties files runs fine on the VM before pushing on to git.

Could somebody please tell us whether its any git editor to VM Vi editor compatibility issue?

Tried opening the files with Notepad++, Notepad, VS Code and pushing back to git and pulling back from git to VM. But didn't work.
Also tried sending files (.sh and .properties)through emails, accessing after copying through WinSCP-- This works fine

********Shell Script initial part **************

filename--> test.sh

```
#########Properties file #############
set -e
properties_file="$1"
     echo `date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` ": $properties_file"
if [ -f "$properties_file" ]
then
     echo `date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` ": Property file \"$properties_file\" found."
    while IFS='=' read -r key value
    do
        key=$(echo $key | tr '.' '_')
         eval ${key}=\${value}
   done < "$properties_file"
else
     echo `date "+%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"` ": Property file not found, Pass property file name as argument."
fi
```

Also assume that test.properties is the properties file

Running on VM:

```
-bash-4.2$sh test.sh test.properties  
ERROR Message:
: invalid optionloy.sh: line 2: set: -
set: usage: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
```

Comment: the code which shared might look with lack of structuring, its because of copying over to this page.

Comment: Please [edit] and use the code formatting tool to structure your question. [so] and the SE network use Markdown for formatting. You can also use the preview at the bottom of the page to make sure it looks right.

Comment: Can you please check now and confirm

Comment: This smells like a newline format problem. You say you used Notepad++, so I'm assuming you write your code in Windows, and maybe stuff gets converted along the way. On your VM, check if the files have DOS newlines and if so, test after converting them to Unix-style. If that solves the problem, there are some Git configuration flags you should review to prevent it from happening again.

Comment: Also vim can be configured to handle some of this, or at least let you knw

Comment: Sure Joanis, will revert back and update

Comment: @Ben, could you please share if you have details on configuring vim ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue here can be the new line characters. To be more specific, Windows DOS uses the “\r\n” and Linux uses the “\n” line ending. When you push the files to git “\n” is replaced with “\r\n”. So you need to remove “\r\n” with “\n”. For this you can use "-sed command `$ sed -i 's/\r$//' file`